# Why is my PC so slow?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.10

I recently changed my OS to Ubuntu from XP via USB because the cd-drive is not very reliable due to the old age of the PC. but still my system requirements are enough to operate Ubuntu. 1.5 GB of RAM, Intel pentium 4 CPU 2.26 GHz with Nvidia fx 5200.

If you need any more details please ask.

Comment: The default Unity desktop requires a fairly powerful PC to run at a reasonable speed but you can try installing a lighter desktop such as [Gnome Classic](http://askubuntu.com/q/58172/107450) or one of the lighter variants as suggested by an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that your system configuration is fine to start Ubuntu, but not so fine to use it perfectly.

I recommend you to use more lightweight Ubuntu derivatives - [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) or [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/), that give you better performance on the same system configuration.

Comment: ok uhh i did install xubuntu but i saw veery minor changes, it's still too slow to use normally. and i tried installing nvidia's driver for my geforve (downloaded a *.run file and installed it using the official method) but after a reboot which was not required i get a blank screen after logging in. now i only see the cursor. how can i fix this?

Comment: ok i fixed it but still it's slow.

Comment: i take my words back the xubuntu has significantly changed the performance

Answer (score 0):

The slowness you encounter is probably linked to the few RAM you have on your PC.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements states that

> From experience, we all know that it is recommended to have 2048 MiB RAM to properly run a day to day Ubuntu.

So as already suggested, you should try changing to lightweigth distros. My solution is you add 1Go to your device if possible.